# conways game of life in ruby

Tags: ruby, conways-game-of-life

I am making conway game of life in ruby. This is my **cell_spec.rb** file. I'm getting failure/error in line 10 as:

```
expect(GameOfLife::Cell.new_dead_cell).to be_dead
```

I have a another file **cell.rb** where class cell is defined. How will implement custom predicate mather in this file?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GameOfLife::Cell do 
  def build_neighbours(live_count)
    [GameOfLife::Cell.new_live_cell] * live_count +
       [GameOfLife::Cell.new_dead_cell] * (8 - live_count)
  end
  context "factory" do
    it "can be dead" do
      expect(GameOfLife::Cell.new_dead_cell).to be_dead
    end

    it "can be alive" do
      expect(GameOfLife::Cell.new_live_cell).to be_alive
    end
  end

  context "live cell generation rules" do
    let(:cell) { GameOfLife::Cell.new_live_cell }

    [0, 1].each do |i|
      it "dies when there are #{i} live neighbours" do
        expect(cell.next_generation(build_neighbours(i))).to be_dead
      end
    end

    [2, 3].each do |i|
      it "lives when there are #{i} live neighbours" do
        expect(cell.next_generation(build_neighbours(i))).to be_alive
      end
    end

    (4..8).each do |i|
      it "dead when there are #{i} live neighbours" do
        expect(cell.next_generation(build_neighbours(i))).to be_dead
      end
    end
  end

  context "dead cell generation rules" do
    let(:cell) { GameOfLife::Cell.new_dead_cell }

    (0..2).each do |i|
      it "dies when there are #{i} live neighbours" do
        expect(cell.next_generation(build_neighbours(i))).to be_dead
      end
    end

    [3].each do |i|
      it "lives when there are #{i} live neighbours" do
        expect(cell.next_generation(build_neighbours(i))).to be_alive
      end
    end

    (4..8).each do |i|
      it "dead when there are #{i} live neighbours" do
        expect(cell.next_generation(build_neighbours(i))).to be_dead
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this is my cell.rb file having cell class.. i want to know the inplementation of code for dead? and alive? methods. plz help me out

```
class GameOfLife::Cell
  ALIVE = "alive"
  DEAD = "dead"

 # lost implementation
  def self.new_dead_cell
     return DEAD
  end

  def self.new_live_cell
    return ALIVE
  end

  def dead?

  end

  def alive?

  end

 end
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: 1) GameOfLife::Cell factory can be dead
      Failure/Error: expect(GameOfLife::Cell.new_dead_cell).to be_dead
       expected dead to respond to `dead?`
     # ./spec/game_of_life/cell_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) GameOfLife::Cell factory can be alive
     Failure/Error: expect(GameOfLife::Cell.new_live_cell).to be_alive
       expected alive to respond to `alive?`
     # ./spec/game_of_life/cell_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: It pretty much tells you what's wrong with your code. In order to make the `be_dead` matcher work, you need to implement the `dead?` method in the `GameOfLife::Cell` class.

Comment: i have implemented dead? method..but this the error is "expected dead to respond to dead?".. how will this problem   be solved                                                                                                  def dead?                                                                                                dead                                                                                                        end

Comment: What do you return from the `new_dead_cell` method? It should return the instance, so the last line should be `self`, unless the last statement in the method already returns the instance.

Comment: Please edit your post if you want to paste longer text and useful info for other readers. If you want to get good answers, you need to make it as easy as possible for readers to quickly get all the necessary information.

Comment: this is code for cell class.. what i need to write in dead? and alive? methods. i  am stuck here        class GameOfLife::Cell
       ALIVE = "alive"
         DEAD = "dead"

        # lost implementation
          def self.new_dead_cell
             return DEAD
          end
    
          def self.new_live_cell
             return ALIVE
          end
    
          def dead?
         
 end
    
       def alive?
      
        end
    
        end

Comment: Please add your cell class to the original question, you can edit it.

Comment: i have added cell.rb file.  i want to know about implmentation of dead? and alive? methods

Comment: What do you want to know about them?

Comment: the code inside dead? and alive?.  i am not able to get what will come inside these methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one obvious way of doing this.
You simply create a new instance of Cell and store its state (as :dead or :alive).
dead? and alive? methods then simply check the state.

```
 class Cell
  ALIVE = :alive
  DEAD = :dead

  def self.new_dead_cell
     new(DEAD)
  end

  def self.new_live_cell
    new(ALIVE)
  end

  def initialize state
    @state = state
  end
  attr_reader :state

  def dead?
    state == DEAD
  end

  def alive?
    state == ALIVE
  end
end
```